# Google cloud engine: Open port 587

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

In my rails app I have email setup with Amazon SES as I was previously using beanstalk.

I have moved to Google Cloud Engine but I want to keep using Amazon SES as the free tier allows up to 50000 emails per day and my app is already coded to process bounces and complaints with the Amazon service.

Amazon state:

```
You need to confirm with your host that ports 465 and 587 are open 
for outgoing SMTP calls. It will not be possible to use Amazon SES 
unless these ports are open.
```

Google state:

```
Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 
25, 465, and 587
```

Is there any way at all to open up ports 587 in my Google Cloud App and use Amazon SES email service? This is extremely frustrating.
Google have guides for sendgrid and mailgun, both of which are irrelevant for me.

Comment: *"Amazon SES as the free tier allows up to 50000 emails per day"*  Where did you get this idea?  I think you'll find the correct number is 2,000 messages per day, and I believe you'll also find that this is only true when you send the messages from inside EC2 -- not elsewhere.  Cite a source for this number, please.

Comment: You start in sandbox. Once you have bounce and complaint handling in place and accept terms and conditions, you can manually ask to be removed from sandbox. Here they will look at your case and raise your sending limits up to 65,000/day. They gave me 50,000/day. Whether this is only via EC2 or not.... I'm not sure now.

Comment: From Amazon FAQ's;  Amazon SES users do not need to sign up for any other AWS services. Any application with Internet access can use Amazon SES to deliver email, whether that application runs in your own data center, within Amazon EC2, or as a client software solution.

Comment: I did not say you couldn't *use* SES externally. You can. And, yes, you can work your way up to a quota of 50,000 or even more messages per day, whether you are sending from inside EC2 or not.  The **scope of the free tier** is the topic of my comment. You said *"the free tier allows up to 50000 emails per day,"* which is incorrect.  The SES free tier is an allowance of 2,000 emails per day *for free* and, according to the pricing page, this free allowance applies to messages sent from within EC2.  Charges for sending messages in excess of the free allowance are billed to your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is in the SES documentation.

> To set up a `STARTTLS` connection, the SMTP client connects to the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint on port 25, 587, or 2587
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html

tl;dr? Use port 2587.

Comment: This does indeed work. It seems they have contradicting documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to use those ports, especially when, as you observed, it's clearly documented that they're not allowed.

A possible approach is to have a simpler app on Amazon, which would just be acting as a relay, if you want, for the GCE app (which would contain the rest of the functionality) by:

- listening for email sending instructions from your GCE app and sending the emails accordingly
- listening for bounces and complaints and relaying them (or rather the relevant info from them) to the GCE app

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I switched from amazon as it is absurdly expensive to leave an app running with them. The costs of having an app running for email purposes is just not worth it. It looks like I'm either going to have to ditch google or amazon just to get emails working, which is just mind boggling. I will continue to look through the docs to see if there is any work around.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Google restrictions on ports `25`, `465`, and `587` an easy workaround is to setup a port forwarding rule and use some other ports.

ie :

> -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 15000 -j 
>   DNAT --to-destination XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:587